# How to onCreateOptionsMenu get called only once during Fragment lifecycle

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

`onCreateOptionsMenu` get called every time when `Fragment` is resuming. Is there any solution to call to `onCreateOptionsMenu` only `once` when Fragment get created?

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
        final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search_hint));
        searchItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                showContacts();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: That's not how Android menus work - every time the Menu is invalidated, the entire menu is thrown away and a new menu is created, necessitating a new call to `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

Answer (score 1):

It's hooked in to the lifecycle, so the method will get called. That doesn't mean your code needs to get called every time. Setup a class level boolean to ensure that code only runs once. Or perhaps do a check of 'getOnActionExpandListener'...

```
if(searchItem.getOnActionExpandListener() == null) {
    searchItem.setOnActionExpandListener.......
}
```